# Playwright - .net - Maximize Browser

Tags: .net, browser, playwright, playwright-dotnet

How to config runsettings to maximize the browser window using Playwright.I tried below code but the browser is not maximized to full mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <HEADED>1</HEADED>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
    </RunConfiguration>
    <Playwright>
        <BrowserName>chromium</BrowserName>
        <ExpectTimeout>5000</ExpectTimeout>
        <LaunchOptions>
            <Channel>chrome</Channel>
            <SlowMo>800</SlowMo>
            <Args>--start-maximized</Args>
        </LaunchOptions>
    </Playwright>
</RunSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to pass args as an array andit worked for me : ["--start-maximized"]

```
<LaunchOptions>
    <Headless>false</Headless>
    <Channel>chrome</Channel>   
    <args>["--start-maximized"]</args>
</LaunchOptions>
```